# How to capture a screenshot using Krypton using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, krypton

[image: File issue][image: error on line 3][image: current code][image: error for line 3]I would like to seek help if there is a possible way / code to capture a screenshot under Krypton platform that uses JAVA selenium. I'm having trouble in terms of it's standardization. Thanks!

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver()
driver.get("https://login.bws.birst.com/login.html/")
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE)
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"))
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the exact problem you are facing in terms of _standardization_ to help us what's going wrong?

Comment: I don't have any code segment for screenshot right now but i have reference using selenium Java but when using it in krypton, it does not work

Comment: That's the reason I am not sure if I can point you to an existing discussion or you require all together a different new answer. Your code trials and error would have helped us to some extent.

Comment: So where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: all the objects are not working, i would like to ask if what should be the proper way when implementing screenshot when using krypton as a platform

Comment: A lot of the contributors may not have access to systems with krypton as a platform and in that case some sample lines of settings/code/error might have helped.

Comment: hello i have update the post with pics hopefully you can see it further more ive attached my current code and the lines for 2 and 3 that ahs error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the screenshots there seems to be some discrepency with the imports/Classes. Further to keep things simpler create destination folder within the *Project Scope* e.g. the **Screenshots** directory below:

[image: screenshot_folder]

To capture a screenshot using *Java* you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  package screenShot;

  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;

  import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
  import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
  import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class takesScreenshot {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://login.bws.birst.com/login.html/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Birst"));
          File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
          FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(".\\Screenshots\\Mads_Cruz_screenshot.png"));
      }
  }
  ```
- Captured Image:

[image: Mads_Cruz_screenshot]

Comment: i'd tried implementing that on my code removing the driver part since i have my own set up. now im having issue on "File scrFile" part but i have my import library for that i don't why it does not work

Comment: please see the latest photo attached. i have import java.io.File; idk why it's still not working